# How to change the cout format for pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, cout

I have to write a C++ program on in VS which does the same as a previously written programm for Solaris which is compiled with gcc.

The following "problem" occured:

```
int var1 = 42;
int* var1Ptr = &var1;
cout << "Address of pointer " << var1Ptr << endl;
```

This code returns in the solaris program a 0x indexed address (0x08FFAFC).

In my VS code it returns as 008FFAFC.

Since we only do comparison within the code it would be fine, but the supportteam have their own tools which extract data from the logs which is looking for those 0x indexed values. Is there a way to format it like this without adding the 0x prefix everytime we write into the logs?

```
cout << "Maybe this way: " << hex << int(&var1Ptr) << endl;
```

doesn't have the effect I wanted.

Comment: Doing `int(&var1Ptr)` will only work on systems where the size of `int` is the same as the size of `&var1Ptr`. Furthermore, `&var1Ptr` will give you a pointers to the variable `var1Ptr`, which is of type `int**`, not the pointer you want to print I guess.

Comment: not sure what you want. With or without 0x ? with zero padding? I'm confused.

Comment: Pardon if it is confusing, its meant with 0x since its already that way in the solaris program

Comment: Joachim you are right, didn't see that since the values only differ a bit, I just looked for the format. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little helper class:

```
namespace detail {

    template<class T>
    struct debug_pointer
    {
        constexpr static std::size_t pointer_digits()
        {
            return sizeof(void*) * 2;
        };
        static constexpr std::size_t width = pointer_digits();

        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const
        {
            std::uintptr_t i = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p);
            return os << "0x" << std::hex << std::setw(width) << std::setfill('0') << i;
        }
        T* p;

        friend
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, debug_pointer const& dp) {
            return dp(os);
        }

    };
}
```

offered via a custom manipulator...

```
template<class T>
auto debug_pointer(T* p)
{
    return detail::debug_pointer<T>{ p };
}
```

allows us this expression:

```
int i;
std::cout << debug_pointer(&i) << std::endl;
```

Which will yield either an 8-digit or 16-digit hex pointer value, depending on your architecture (mine is 64-bit):

```
0x00007fff5fbff3bc
```

Comment: thank you very much. Do you know why VS compiler lets the program return it in a different format than gcc? since the same libraries are included

Comment: @Thorvason the standard does not specify the format. Therefore implementations may do as they please. Therefore, a program will have undefined behaviour if it depends on the output format.